# element.getBoundingClientRect() returning wrong co-ordinates in FF and Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have an object called 'element'. After refresh is performed i want to get back to same updated field in table. Am trying to find the co-ordinates for the object(Basically it's a table row). 
The below snippet is working fine for IE. But in FF and Chrome its not working.
as it is returning wrong values.

```
    var x = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    alert(x.top);
```

How can i get the exact co-ordinates in FF and chrome? if not possible through above code, Is there any alternative approach?

Can anyone please explain?

Comment: My goodness, is something actually working in IE that Chrome and Firefox fail at? Now there's a novelty. Oh, that and animated background gradients. IE does those pretty awesomely too.

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to be factoring in the page's current scroll position.

When you reload a page, most browsers will scroll you back to where you were before reloading ([a pretty useful feature](http://xkcd.com/1309/)).

It's probable that IE is evaluating the `getBoundingClientRect` before scrolling to where you were before the reload, whereas Chrome and Firefox are doing the scrolling first.

Comment: I am using iFames.. in the Frame1 i have a table. when i select a record in Frame1, all the fields in the record will be displayed in Frame2. So,If i give new values for the record in Frame2, Then Frame1 should be refreshed and focus should be on updated record. In IE its working fine. Whereas in FF and chrome, Am not able to see the updated record as the scroll function is not working properly because of wrong co-ordinates are being passed to scrollTo(x,y) method. Can you please suggest on this? @Niet the Dark Absol

Comment: Since you have a reference to the row, consider trying `element.scrollIntoView()` instead, or possibly `element.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded()`.

Comment: Now in IE there is a problem :(.. Whereas in FF and Chrome it is  Working Fine :)

Comment: "a problem" - can you be more specific?

Comment: After refresh performed on Frame1, Every time it is taking to the top. Actually, the view disappears and scroll bar will go the top

Comment: Hmm... perhaps add a short `setTimeout` or use the `onload` event of the iframe before calling `scrollIntoView`?

Comment: I have Element. Is there any other approach, which can replace 'getBoundingClientRect()' functionality, to get co-ordinates.

Comment: You shouldn't need `getBoundingClientRect` - `scrollIntoView` handles the "finding where it is" bit for you.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note is getBoundingClientRect() returns values as if the page was displayed at 100% zoom (at least in Chrome), regardless of the actual zoom level.

This can be solved by multiplying them by window.devicePixelRatio